# Микрофронтенды, single-spa меняет глобальные переменные

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Использую Nuxt2 и single-spa. Микрофронт работает. Перед посещением микрофронта доступна глобальная переменная $nuxt. После посещения микрофронта $nuxt меняется безвозвратно. Как предотвратить изменения глобальных переменных библиотекой single-spa?

*subapp/index.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="__subapp" key="subapp"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { registerApplication, start, getAppNames, unregisterApplication } from "single-spa"

export default {
  created() {
    if(!getAppNames().includes('subapp')){
      registerApplication({
        name: 'subapp',
        app: async () => await import('~/../sub-app/dist/_nuxt/subapp'),
        activeWhen: '/subapp'
      });
      start();
    }
  },
  async beforeDestroy() {
    await unregisterApplication('subapp')
  }
}
</script>
```